# How to Properly Synchronize GPU Rendering and Presentation in a Command Queue?

Tags: c++, gpu, directx, directx-12

I'm working on a graphics application where I use a command queue to render scenes. However, I'm facing some uncertainty about when to call Present for my swapchain to ensure that I'm not presenting an incomplete frame.

It's important to note that I do not wait for the GPU to finish its work before starting to render the next frame.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
void CommandQueue::BeginFrame(ID3D12PipelineState* pPSO)
{
    CHECK_FAILURE(m_commandAllocators[m_frameIndex]->Reset());
    CHECK_FAILURE(m_commandList->Reset(m_commandAllocators[m_frameIndex].Get(), pPSO));
}

void CommandQueue::EndFrame()
{
    CHECK_FAILURE(m_commandList->Close());
    const uint64 currentFenceValue = m_fenceValues[m_frameIndex];
    CHECK_FAILURE(m_commandQueue->Signal(m_fence.Get(), currentFenceValue));

    // Update the frame index.
    m_frameIndex = m_frameIndex + 1 % QUEUE_FRAMES_COUNT;

    // If the next frame is not ready to be rendered yet, wait until it is ready.
    if (m_fence->GetCompletedValue() < m_fenceValues[m_frameIndex])
    {
        CHECK_FAILURE(m_fence->SetEventOnCompletion(m_fenceValues[m_frameIndex], m_fenceEvent));
        WaitForSingleObjectEx(m_fenceEvent, INFINITE, FALSE);
    }
    // Set the fence value for the next frame.
    m_fenceValues[m_frameIndex] = currentFenceValue + 1;
}
```

When and where I should call Present to ensure that I present a fully rendered frame without potential issues, given that I don't wait for the GPU to complete its work before initiating the next frame's rendering?

Comment: Regarding "any code examples or best practices would be greatly appreciated", have you checked the official DX12 _Hello World_ sample? What about Luna's _Intro to Game Programming with DX12_. There's also _DirectX Tool Kit for DX12_. These sources should be consulted first before following other arbitrary tutorials you can find across the internet.

Comment: After `Signal` before `WaitForSingleObjectEx`. Just copy paste from https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12HelloWorld/src/HelloFrameBuffering and don't think too much is my advice